# Download Drupal Documentation?

Tags: drupal, documentation

I would like to download documentation of the Drupal hooks, and whatever else would be useful. I've been saving a few pages piecemeal to my hard drive, but it would take too long to download the entire api.drupal.org this way. Is there someplace where I can get it all at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal's documentation is all directly from the source code. You can use [the API module](http://drupal.org/project/api) to use the in-code documentation to generate your own local version of api.drupal.org.

Comment: I believe that it is all in doxygen format so once you have the code you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen to generate a PDF if you so wish.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you have api.module installed on a local copy of Drupal, you can see browse and search the documentation embedded in contrib modules like Views, Organic Groups, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you use windows, try this link http://drupal.kollm.org/chm-drupal-6
This good fella has created a very handy CHM file

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is great for API documentation, but for the various other guides on the drupal.org handbooks page it is a little more painful.

[Found this here](http://drupal.org/node/472396) which explains how logging into the site reveals the printer friendly version links